# php email() with image

Tags: php, email

Using outlook I can send emails with images inserted into message body(not as attachment). How can i do that using mail() function from PHP?

Comment: Technically PHP does not have an `email()` function. You mean `mail()`, right?

Comment: yes, ur right...i've correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to host the images someplace and would them to to be included inline, you'll need to do is encode them, insert the encoded text and reference them by ID.  PHPmailer handles this pretty nicely (see Inline Attachments):

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tutorial#3

Otherwise, you can just reference them by their web address as described in the other posts.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend Swift Mailer:

http://swiftmailer.org/docs/embedding-files

Answer (score 3):

#### From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) (Example #4 Sending HTML email):

Note the `$message` variables contents, and the value of the `$headers` variable.

```
$to       = "john@doe.com";
$subject  = "HTML Email";
$message  = "Hello <img src='http://mysite.com/world.jpg' />";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: HTML Emailer <auto@example.com>' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the emails are in html/mime format you could do it as html...

Answer (score 2):

I have used HTML Mime Email extensively, and it is very straightforward:

http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/32.html

```
$mail = new htmlMimeMail();
$mailhtml = $mail->getFile('./emailheader.html');
$mailimglogo = $mail->getFile('./images/email-logo-1.jpg');
$mail->addHTMLImage($mailimglogo, 'email-logo-1.jpg', 'image/jpeg');
$mailhtml .= '<tr><td class="mailheader" colspan="2" align="center">';
$mailhtml .= '<img src="email-logo-1.jpg"></td></tr>';

...


$mailhtml .= $mail->getFile('./emailfooter.html');
$mail->setHtml($mailhtml);
$mail->setFrom('Dana Brainerd <dana@danabrainerdphotography.com>');
$mail->setCc('adam@adamcasey.net');
$mail->setBcc('webmaster@danabrainerdphotography.com');
$mail->setSubject("Dana Brainerd Photography Order Number {$roworder['order_number']}");

$mailresult = $mail->send(array($roworder['customer_email']));
```